# PHP check subdomain and language, then redirect accordingly will not stop refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, refresh

So, i've got the script below and the problem right now is just one, it does not stop refreshing..i've tried numerous conditions and it always does the same.

can you help?
*Note: i must keep the refresh script, no header location or http refresh.*

```
<?php                       

// language start

require ('language.functions.php');

$language = language(); 

    // Whether or not to output debug code
    //DEFINE("DEBUG", 1);
    DEFINE("DEBUG", 0);

    // An array of actual subdomains on the server
    $real_subdomains = array('us','emea','asia');

    // The domain info for this site
    $domain_name = 'example';
    $domain_tld = '.com';

    // Set a variable to hold the host info
    $host_info = '';

    // Check to see if 'register_globals' is on

    // if(ini_set('register_globals' == 1))
    //  {
        $host_info = $HTTP_HOST;
    //  }
    // else
    //  {
    //  $host_info = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    //  }

    // Break up the pieces of the host info
    $parts = explode(".", $host_info);

    // Pull the 'subdomain' for the url
    $subdomain = $parts[0];

    (DEBUG) ? print "Host Info: " . $host_info : '';

    // Check that the subdomain isn't 'www' or the domain name
    if(($subdomain != "www") && ($subdomain != $domain_name))
        {
        // Is the subdomain a real domain?
        if(in_array($subdomain, $real_subdomains))
        {
        //  exit

        }
        else
        {
    // refresh browser to correct domain
    $newurl = 'http://' . $language . '.' . $domain_name . $domain_tld  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = '$newurl' </script>";
        }
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check if subdomain is not a language code as well :)

```
if($subdomain != "www" && $subdomain != $domain_name && $subdomain != $language)
```

or

```
if(!in_array($subdomain,array("www",$domain_name,$language)))
```

Than, after redirecting to eg. http://pl.stackoverflow.com you won't keep looping. I would consider this condition to be after

```
$language = language();
```

just to avoid other operations if there is no need to redirect.

Also, you should consider rewriting the code. I am not sure if its bulletproof (www.ex.example.com, www.pl.ex.example.com, pl.ex.example.com, ex.example.com etc.).

Comment: ok,, so i tried both your suggestions and, although the condition is correct i still have no luck :( still looping.
Regarding the code rewrite for sub-subdomains, i have no need for that for this projec.